TypeError ".deploy()" is not a function npx hardhat test
I'm new to hardhat and solidity. I'm trying to basic example that I found online, however I always get this error at testing.
Here is my hardhat.config.js settings
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.19",
};

my code is very simple as follows
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

contract SayHello{
    string public sayHi = "SayHello MM";
}

and my test code is as follows
describe ("Testing the Say Hello contract",()=>{

let myContact;
    beforeEach(async()=>{
        const ContractSayHello = await ethers.getContractFactory("SayHello");
        myContact= await ContractSayHello.deploy();
        await myContact.deployed();
        })

    it("get say hi string", async()=>{

expect( await myContact.sayHi()).to.equal("tmam")

    })
})

Why am I keep getting the same error?
Thanks in advance.
I'm trying to test a code and gives me errors


ReferenceError: expect is not defined

As for this error, did you include import of chai into your test suite?
import { expect } from "chai";

